# Test failing in get :index with wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1) using Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I have a very simple RSpec controller test that looks like this:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe IndexController, type: :controller do
  describe 'GET #index' do
    it 'returns http success' do
      get :index
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
    end
  end
end
```

and it fails with the error:

```
  1) IndexController GET #index returns http success
     Failure/Error: get :index

     ActionView::Template::Error:
       wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)
     # ./spec/controllers/index_controller_spec.rb:6:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ------------------
     # --- Caused by: ---
     # ArgumentError:
     #   wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)
     #   ./spec/controllers/index_controller_spec.rb:6:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Line 6 is `get :index`. Why is it claiming 2 arguments? only 1 is given.

The controller looks like this:

```
class IndexController < ApplicationController
end
```

and there's a view in `app/views/index/index.html.erb` that looks like this:

```
Nothing to see here.
```

It works correctly with this route: `root to: 'index#index'`.

Any ideas what's wrong here?

Comment: Unless this is a legacy app skip controller specs completely and just go for request specs. Their use is discouraged. https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails#request-specs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/2177

I fixed it by upgrading to `rails-rspec` 4.0.0, at this time, a beta:

```
gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 4.0.0.beta4' # 4.0.0.beta4 due to https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/2177
```